# PHP script seems not to free memory properly maybe due to database interaction

Tags: php, database, memory, memory-management

I have a very complex script written in PHP which reads in a lot of CSV files and imports the content into a database. At some places I'm not doing this directly via INSERT statements but through objects.

My problem is that top (the script is running on ubuntu 10.04 with PHP 5.3.2) shows the apache2 process to consume several GB of memory while memory_get_usage(true) will stick around  250 MB. I started calling gc_collect_cycles() which stated to collect over 100000 cycles at times but still the consumed memory does not decrease. I started to unset variables before leaving function scopes and all that.

Is there a way to track the reason for the enormous memory usage and much more importantly a way to fix it?

Comment: have you tried freeing up the variables each time you are finished loading a file?

Comment: Change PHP version from non-existing 6 to 5 :-)

Comment: @MelvinProtacio Yes. I call unset on all variables that are not used in more then on loop or such.

Comment: how about result sets? and file variables? more likely, the culprit is the allocated memory when you open files. you may have missed freeing up the resources that are being generated when you get a result from mysql queries and when you open the files.

Comment: @MelvinProtacio It's very probably the result sets... I have to work in the confines of an existing application which abstracts db calls to work with several engines. Very probably the results are not freed... But shouldn't leaving the function scope or destroying the calling object free the result?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/)?

I've used it before to get a look at resource consumption, and you can often see quickly which calls are costing the most. It can take some time to process output from large apps, but may be worth it.